# Facebook PHP SDK V5 - Get Page Access Token Not User Access Token

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to figure out how to post to a Facebook fan page as the "voice of the page" as Facebook calls it.

I have the following code:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([  
      'app_id' => '17xxxxxxxxxx',  
      'app_secret' => 'exxxxxxxxxx',  
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',  
      ]);  

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    try {
      $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      // There was an error communicating with Graph
      echo $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }

    if (isset($accessToken)) {
      // User authenticated your app!
      // Save the access token to a session and redirect
      $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
      // Log them into your web framework here . . .
      // Redirect here . . .
      print_r($accessToken);

            //// get following data from the db or just replace them ////

            $params["message"] = $title;
            $params["link"] = $targetUrl;
            $params["picture"] = $imgUrl;
            $params["description"] = $description;

            // post to Facebook
            try {
              // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
              $response = $fb->post('/229101234342377163/feed', $params, $accessToken);
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
              echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
              exit;
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
              echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
              exit;
            }

            $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```

When this runs I get the error:

```
Graph returned an error: Unsupported post request.
```

From what I understand, I need to access the page token that I am trying to post to? How can I do this? Please help!

Answer (score -1):

You need to get a page access token too, here's how to do it. It will give you a list of all your pages with their corresponding access tokens.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens

The "Unsupported post request" could also mean that your application is in testing mode still.